# Bibliography module and zen subtheme - export not working properly

Tags: theming

I have a problem with the [Bibliography Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/biblio) and a [zen subtheme](https://www.drupal.org/node/873778) in D7. When I go to the main /biblio page, to watch all my publications, up right there is my export all link "Export 0 results: BibTex". It is zero, though there are several publications showed and when I click on the BibTex link I can download them all as a bib-file properly.

In the moment I switch to any other theme or the zen main theme (no subtheme) the zero is disappearing and the proper number shows up next to the export link. Even when I use a plan new zen subtheme, without any customizations, it does not work again.

What could be the issue here, any ideas?